# Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, copy, pass-by-reference, defaultdict

I am having some trouble understanding this, I have tried to reduce the problem to this set of code

```
for k in y.keys():
    if k in dateDict.keys():

        if yearDict[k] in dict1:
            dict1[yearDict[k]].extend(y[k])
        else:
            dict1[yearDict[k]] = y[k]

        if yearDict[k] in dict2:
            dict2[yearDict[k]].extend(y[k])
        else:
            dict2[yearDict[k]] = y[k]
    else:
        continue
```

I have two dictionaries `y` and `dateDict` to begin with. For a matching key for `y` in `dateDict`, I am populating two other dictionaries `dict1` and `dict2`, hashed with keys from some other dictionary `yearDict`. Unfortunately the result are duplicated in `dict1` and `dict2`, I have values repeating themselves. Any idea what could be happening?

Also I notice that this code works as expected,

```
for k in y.keys():
    if k in dateDict.keys():

        if yearDict[k] in dict1:
            dict1[yearDict[k]].extend(y[k])
        else:
            dict1[yearDict[k]] = y[k]
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: Is `y[k]` a list as well?

Comment: Are you sure you want the distinct `dictl` and `dict1`?

Comment: @Kolmar yes, and Rafael not sure how you mean?

Comment: `if yearDict[k] in dict1: dictl[yearDict[k]].extend(y[k])`. Notice how the name `dict1` in `if` has digit `1` in it, but the name `dictl` after the colon has letter `l`. Is it intended?

Comment: In your example, you have `dictl` (with an `l`) and `dict1` (with a 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `y[k]` is a list (which it looks like), the same list will be assigned to everywhere where is it used. Dictionaries do not make copies of the elements when they are assigned, they just keep references to their objects. In your example, both keys in `dict1` and `dict2` will point to the **same** object.

Later, when it is modified, the *same* elements will be appended with the new values, once for each map. To prevent this, you can create a new list when initially assigning:

```
dictl[yearDict[k]] = list(y[k])
```

However, it is always good to know the Python standard library. This code could be made much more readable, and without the error, by using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

# This goes wherever the dictionaries 
# where initially defined.
dict1 = defaultdict(list)
dict2 = defaultdict(list)

# You can get the value here, no need to search it later.
for k, value in y.items():
    if k in dateDict.keys():
        # No need to call this everywhere.
        new_key = yearDict[k]

        # Note the defaultdict magic.
        dict1[new_key].extend(value)
        dict2[new_key].extend(value)

    # No need for the 'continue' at the end either.
```

When asked for a key that does not exist yet, the `defaultdict` will create a new one on the fly -- so you don't have to care about initialization, or creating copies of you values.

Comment: I see that Rafael that is interesting, why does that happen, that behavior seems odd?

Comment: Not odd at all. Parameters are set by reference. So each dict actually keeps a reference to the elements they contain -- In your example, they all kept references to the same object.